# Trouble installing Azure RM Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with an elevated PS shell. The appropriate version of PowershellGet is installed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-4.1.0

When trying to follow the above directions I receive this error below:

PackageManagement\Install-Package : Package 'AzureRM.profile' failed to be installed because: /tmp/1323106488/AzureRM.profile/AzureRM.profile.nuspec                                                                                    At /opt/microsoft/powershell/6.0.0alpha.14/Modules/PowerShellGet/1.1.2.0/PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21                                                                                                                                         + ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters                                                                                                                                                                  +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (AzureRM.profile:String) [Install-Package], Exception                                                                                                                                               + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Package '{0}' failed to be installed because: {1},Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

Did I miss a step?

Comment: updated answer.  
I was thinking you are trying to INSTALL Ubuntu on Azure not install AzureRM on Ubuntu (which is impossible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you are applying a windows tutorial to a ubuntu box and wondering why that doesn't work...

```
Install-Package -Name AzureRM.NetCore.Preview -Source https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2 -ProviderName NuGet -ExcludeVersion -Destination <Folder you want this to be installed>
```

you can follow [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jessicadeen/azure/getting-started-with-powershell-core-and-azurerm-modules-on-ubuntu-and-os-x/) to install AzureRM.Profile and AzureRm.Resources (i think those are the only ones ported as of now).

<strike>There was an experimental docker image with some other modules laying around, I can't seem to find it now</strike>

```
docker run -it twitchax/azure-powershell-core
```

here you are; this one has:

```
AzureRM.Compute.Netcore
AzureRM.Network.Netcore
AzureRM.Profile.Netcore
AzureRM.Resources.Netcore
AzureRM.Storage.Netcore
AzureRM.Tags.Netcore
AzureRM.Websites.Netcore
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work on my first attempts so I tried the one above. Totally worked now. Thank you!

Comment: Tried the AzureRM.Netcore.Preview I accepted thanks again